# Style Unordered List Independently From Parent Unordered List

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, html-lists

I'm not sure if I formulated the question correctly, but let me try to explain what I want to achieve.

I'm trying to style navigation menu of a WordPress-based site.

I want the submenu links to be evenly arranged along the entire width of the website's `<body>` tag (960px wide). If the links of a particular submenu do not fit in one row, I want them to wrap around and arrange themselves in neat columns.

Finally, I want the submenu, when it drops down on hover, to push the rest of the website's content down.

**Problem:** the submenu unordered list affects the position of the links in the parent unordered list, moving the links around. Somehow, the only thing I could do to keep the parent menu links in place was to pull the submenus out of the way by applying `margin-right:-965px;`

**Question:** How should I modify my CSS to position both submenus all the way to the left, level with the edge of the main container?

(If necessary, I can assign custom classes to each submenu separately, for example: .submenu-about and .submenu-investors.)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here's the complete CSS for the navigation menu:

```
.main-navigation ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin-top:45px;
}

.main-navigation ul {
display: inline-block;
width:70%;
float:right;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
float:left;
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
display:block;
margin:3px 0 3px 40px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
background:#efefef;
display:none;
}

.main-navigation li {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.main-navigation li a {
outline: none;
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom: 0;
color: #6a6a6a;
text-transform: uppercase;
//white-space: nowrap;
}

.main-navigation li a:hover {
color: #000;
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
margin:-1px -960px 3px 0;
display:block;
width:960px;
}

.main-navigation li ul li a {
font-size: 11px;
margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
width:180px;
}

.main-navigation .menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .menu-ancestor > a,
.main-navigation .page_item > a,
.main-navigation .page_ancestor > a {
color: #9a9a9a;
font-weight:bold;
}

.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
color: #636363;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer.

1. Remove the background from `ul li:hover ul`.
2. Set `position:relative` and the gray background for the `ul li:hover >ul li`.
3. Set individually the negative left margins for each submenu `li` item, to pull them left separately by different number of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

This Should do it

Add this to your css

```
.main-navigation ul li .sub-menu {position:absolute; left:0px;}
```

Comment: LOL, yeah, that would be a great solution, @Satish, wouldn't it? The problem is, I want the submenu to push the rest of the content of the page down (as I mentioned in my question). Which, of course, can;t happen if the position of submenu is absolute. Do you think there may be an alternative solution, the one not relying on absolute positioning? I'd appreciate your advice.